# CodeIgniter doesn't understand where in two update queries

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two functions in my model. First one:

```
    public function updateOwn($game,$own,$user) {

    $data = array(
        'own' => $own
    );

    $q = $this->db->where(array(
        'game' => $game,
        'user' => $user
    ));

    $q = $this->db->update('ownership',$data);

    if($q) { return true; } else { return false; }
}
```

and the secound one:

```
    public function updateRate($game,$rate,$user) {

    $data = array(
        'rate' => $rate
    );

    $q = $this->db->where(array(
        'game' => $game,
        'user' => $user
    ));

    $q = $this->db->update('rates',$data);
    $q = $this->db->update('ownership',$data);

    if($q) { return true; } else { return false; }
}
```

The problem is, first one is working, secound one isn't. I mean, it works, but it updates every row, not just those with matching `game` and `user`. Variables are passed fine.

Comment: try separate `where` ... `$this->db->where('game', $game);` `$this->db->where('user', $user);` see if it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The where condition is only applied to the first update statement. Try below.

```
$data = array(
    'rate' => $rate
);

$where = array(
    'game' => $game,
    'user' => $user
);

$q = $this->db->update('rates', $data, $where);
$q = $this->db->update('ownership', $data, $where);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the where array as a third parameter to make sure it is working properly:

```
$q = $this->db->update('rates',$data,array(
        'game' => $game,
        'user' => $user
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter resets a lot of the query params that you build after you execute it. You'll need to re-add the WHERE clauses after the first update() call.

```
public function updateRate($game,$rate,$user) {

$data = array(
    'rate' => $rate
);

$q = $this->db->where(array(
    'game' => $game,
    'user' => $user
));

$q = $this->db->update('rates',$data);
$q = $this->db->where(array(
        'game' => $game,
        'user' => $user
    ));
$q = $this->db->update('ownership',$data);
if($q) { return true; } else { return false; }
}
```

Comment: sure... I just copied it from the OP, and it's not directly related to this question... do you have a thought on it? Feel free to edit my answer or provide your own if the part about the WHERE in the UPDATEs is distinct.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do you need to set $q variable every time? Second, in the last statement you check only if second query was done.

I would do something like:

```
public function updateRate($game,$rate,$user) {
  $data = array(
    'rate' => $rate
  );

  $this->db->where('game', $game)->where('user', $user);
  $first_query = $this->db->update('rates',$data);

  $this->db->where('game', $game)->where('user', $user);
  $second_query = $this->db->update('ownership',$data);

  return $first_query && $second_query;
}
```