# Issue in updating contract record in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, database-design

I am trying to update each contract I have for a particular job entry. My condition is for every job I post, more than one applicant can be hired. Right now, this is what my code shows.

```
Job ID | Job Title | Provider | Contract Status | Provider's Feedback   | Note to Self
1      | First job.| Provider1| DONE            |                       |I like his work.
1      | First job.| Provider2| DONE            |                       |I like his work.
```

This is supposedly correct but just until PROVIDER column. Whenever I click job title entry (I have it linked to another page where I can update the contract), I should be able to write something about the worker - if the job was done, how his performance was (which should be view-able on his equivalent page), and  my note to self about him. Problem is, whenever I click one of the contracts and make an update, all the contracts will be affected. How will I make it unique?

Here's my code so far:

```
public function update_job_contract($post_obj)
{
    $id = $post_obj['id'];
    $data = array 
    (
        'client_feedback' => $post_obj['client_feedback'],
        'client_notetoself' => $post_obj['client_notetoself'],
        'contract_status' => $post_obj['contract_status'],
        'client_id' => $this->auth_model->get_user_id()
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('job', $data);
}
```

in my **controller**:

```
public function update_job_contract() 
{
    $this->validateRole('client');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    $id = $this->uri->segment(3,0);

    $data['job'] = $this->job_model->get_job($id);  

    $this->load->view('client/update_job_contract', $data);
}   

public function update_job_contract_submit() 
{
    $this->validateRole('client');
    $this->load->model('job_model');

    //if ( '0' == $_POST['id'] ) {
    $this->job_model->update_job_contract($_POST);
    //}
    redirect('client/manage_job_contracts?message=Congratulations!');
}
```

I am looking forward to getting help! Thanks!

Comment: Please explain more your table structure (is provider unique? what is job ID and why it is not unique), enable profiler via `$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);` and see your queries that are sent to database.

Comment: Hi Kyslik. Thanks for your response.Yes, provider is unique. Job ID is the id automatically assigned to any new job post created. It is not unique in this case, because I made it possible in my code to allow more than one provider to be hired for it..

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter doesn't understand where in two update queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930193/codeigniter-doesnt-understand-where-in-two-update-queries)